# Get nodeID in BFS cytoscape Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I'm using cytoscape.js to make BFS search in custom made graph's. I need to add every node ID which has been visited in this search. I've tried something like that

```
document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += v.id;
```

in bfs function

```
var bfs = cy.elements().bfs('#1', function(v, e, u, i, depth){}, false);
```

But it's not working, I'm new in JS and programming for any advice I will be thankful.

Comment: Did you try to add the selection to the callback within the Bfs function?

Comment: Hi Darkeez, thanks for sharing your question about this topic! Just on little thing about the tagging: [cytoscape](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cytoscape/info) and [cytoscape.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cytoscape.js/info) are quite different in many aspects and shouldn't be tagged if using the other one. For future posts, please consider using the cytoscape.js tag for mor people with js knowledge to see your question. Thanks!

Comment: Do you still work on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the id of each visited node of bfs, you can, as it is also explained right [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.breadthFirstSearch), use the visit function like this:

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [
    {
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'height': '60px',
        'width': '60px',
        'border-color': 'black',
        'border-opacity': '1',
        'border-width': '10px'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: '$node > node',
      css: {
        'padding-top': '10px',
        'padding-left': '10px',
        'padding-bottom': '10px',
        'padding-right': '10px',
        'text-valign': 'top',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'background-color': '#bbb'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ':selected',
      css: {
        'background-color': 'black',
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'source-arrow-color': 'black'
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
            nodes: [
              { data: { id: 'n0' } },
              { data: { id: 'n1' } },
              { data: { id: 'n2' } },
              { data: { id: 'n3' } },
              { data: { id: 'n4' } },
              { data: { id: 'n5' } },
              { data: { id: 'n6' } },
              { data: { id: 'n7' } },
              { data: { id: 'n8' } },
              { data: { id: 'n9' } },
              { data: { id: 'n10' } },
              { data: { id: 'n11' } },
              { data: { id: 'n12' } },
              { data: { id: 'n13' } },
              { data: { id: 'n14' } },
              { data: { id: 'n15' } },
              { data: { id: 'n16' } }
            ],
            edges: [
              { data: { source: 'n0', target: 'n1' } },
              { data: { source: 'n1', target: 'n2' } },
              { data: { source: 'n1', target: 'n3' } },
              { data: { source: 'n2', target: 'n7' } },
              { data: { source: 'n2', target: 'n11' } },
              { data: { source: 'n2', target: 'n16' } },
              { data: { source: 'n3', target: 'n4' } },
              { data: { source: 'n3', target: 'n16' } },
              { data: { source: 'n4', target: 'n5' } },
              { data: { source: 'n4', target: 'n6' } },
              { data: { source: 'n6', target: 'n8' } },
              { data: { source: 'n8', target: 'n9' } },
              { data: { source: 'n8', target: 'n10' } },
              { data: { source: 'n11', target: 'n12' } },
              { data: { source: 'n12', target: 'n13' } },
              { data: { source: 'n13', target: 'n14' } },
              { data: { source: 'n13', target: 'n15' } },
            ]
          },

  layout: {
    name: 'dagre',
    padding: 5
  }
});


// here is the important part of the code
var idList = [];            // list for id storage
var bfs = cy.elements().bfs({
  roots: '#n0',
  visit: function (v, e, u, i, depth) {
    console.log("The id of the node " + i +  " is " + v.id());   // i is the number of the i'th visited node, v is the node itself
    idList[i] = v.id();
  },
  directed: false
});
```

```css
body { 
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cy"></div>
</body>
</html>
```